# Blink Sketch not be uploaded in Arduino Nano using IDE 2.3.2

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-nano

I do have an Arduino Nano with the MEGA328P microcontroller. I downloaded the Arduino IDE 2.3.2 and the Drive CH341SER.

When I attempt to upload a Blink Sketch there is an Error Output :

"Sketch uses 932 bytes (3%) of program storage space. Maximum is 30720 bytes. Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes. avrude: stk500_recv()
[Microcontroller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4t1w.jpg)
[Error Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGT6U.jpg)